# Segmentation fault for higher values of n(e.g n=999997)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, dynamic-programming

I am using dynamic programming for a problem where I will be given n and need to output minimum number of operations to get 1 from n by using these three operations( -1 ,/2 ,/3). Given constraint(1<=n<=10^6)
My code is giving ***segmentation fault(somewhere in solve function)*** for higher values of n(e.g 977775,1000000) but running fine of smaller input(e.g 100000).
I have tried a lot but I am unable to find problem in my code. Also is there any other way I can apply dynamic programming in this question.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int solve(int n,int a[])
{
    if(n==1)
    return 0;
    if(a[n]!=-1)
    return a[n];
    int ans=100000;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            a[n]=solve(n-1,a)+1;
            if(a[n]<ans)
            ans=a[n];
        }
        else if(i==1 && n%2==0)
        {
            a[n]=solve(n/2,a)+1;
            if(a[n]<ans)
            ans=a[n];
        }
        else if(i==2 && n%3==0)
        {
            a[n]=solve(n/3,a)+1;
            if(a[n]<ans)
            ans=a[n];
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n+1];
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    a[i]=-1;
    int ans=solve(n,a);
    cout<<ans<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int a[n+1];` is a variable-length array and part of standard C++. I know only one compiler that supports it. Are you aware that the memory for VLA is allocated on the stack? That's your problem. The stack size is too small. Use heap memory.

Comment: The cause may be stack overflow. Please consider using `std::vector<int> a(n+1);` instead of `int a[n+1];`.

Comment: The cause may be stack overflow caused by calling function recursively too much. If this is the case, using `std::vector` won't solve this problem.

Comment: Using vector is still causing overflow.   @ThomasSablik I used int *a  = new int[n+1] instead but it is still showing segmentation fault. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: As @MikeCAT implies, the problem is likely related to your function recursively calling itself too often. Using a `std::vector` won't, in itself, fix that. However, if you *do* use a `vector`, be sure to pass it as an argument **by reference** (with `int solve(int n, vector<int>& a)` - note the `&`), otherwise, the entire vector will be copied on each call.

Comment: Ok @AdrianMole I'll remember that(and already used &). Please help me if you know about heap allocation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No form of allocation will help if your recursion depth gets too much. A quick test on my PC (64-bit windows) has your code crashing (with `n = 100000`) after ~10,670 calls to `solve`. That's a lot of stack frames being eaten.

Comment: Okay @AdrianMole, but is there any other way to apply dynamic programming in this question.

Comment: @AvikSingla *(somewhere in solve function)* -- So you don't know exactly where the problem is?  Are you using a debugger, because a debugger will tell you exactly what causes the problem.

Comment: Yes @PaulMcKenzie tried to use onlinegdb debugger. It is showing following - Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x00000000004008af in solve ( n=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7feffc>,a=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7feff0>) at main.cpp:4.    I am not able find where actual problem is from this. ( It may be due to number of recursive calls.)

Comment: Run the code locally and debug the code.  Don't use the online compiler debugging.

Comment: C++ is not a good language for deep recursion.  Most C++ compilers do not do tail recursion optimization, so there is a danger of blowing the stack for any unbounded or deep recursion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can only store up to 8 digits in an int variable in C++, I would switch from int ans to double ans to fix the problem, also keep in mind that double can store up to 34 digits, if you try to do store more digits than the maximum allowed number of digits, weird things happen, and in that case you get a stackOverflow..... Also consider the following: In your function, you are calling about 999997 recusive calls * 3 which is about 3000000 recusive calls for the stack, which is going to use way too much memory and hence Segmentation fault.....

Comment: An IEEE-754 `double` can store ~17 digits. I think you mean `long long int`.

Comment: Ooh yes I realized that. Is there any other way I can apply dynamic programming in this question. And also sorry but constraint in the question is 1<=n<=10^6 and ans will always be less than n. That's why I used int only. And I think if ans exceeds 8 integers for int that will be integer overflow not stackoverflow. Thanks a lot.

Comment: "you can only store up to 8 digits in an int variable in C++" is not true in typical environment where `int` is 32-bit signed integer, which can store integers upto `2**31 - 1 = 2147483647`. In this case, all 9-digit integers can be stored in `int` variable.